# Creating custom textured armour sets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-optifine

**Minecraft Version**: 1.19.3

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm trying to add a custom texture for a leather armour set in Minecraft via `customModelData`.

For some reason however, it's not working! I'm very clueless as to what I could possibly be doing wrong.

Here is my properties file:

```
type=armor
items=leather_helmet\ leather_chestplate\ leather_leggings\ leather_boots
texture.leather_layer_1=empty
texture.leather_layer_1_overlay=sweetheart_armor_layer_1
texture.leather_layer_2=empty
texture.leather_layer_2_overlay=sweetheart_armor_layer_2
nbt.CustomModelData=6000
```

Here are the attached PNG layers (enlarged for improved viewing):

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

I have everything situated in the directory `~/assets/minecraft/optifine/cit/`. I have countless other models that work, just this one doesn't.

As a follow up question, what are the "overlay" elements of the properties file and are they relevant? I have tried every combination possible. Leaving overlays empty and layers defined. Leaving overlays defined and layers empty, etc etc. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.